# vue faile to load mount component

Tags: vue.js

I have to do some simple thing.
I have to generate different select options to generate different data.

So I create component and I passing array with values, but only in theory xD

When I go to road i got error cold:

```
app.js:37990 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render 
function not defined.

found in

---> <SelectComponent> at resources/js/components/SelectComponent.vue
   <ExampleComponent> at resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue
     <Root>
```

My component is simple for test do,

```
<h1> test connection </h1>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'SelectComponent',
  data () {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

my main component

```
import SelectComponent from './SelectComponent.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    SelectComponent,
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
}
```

where is my issue?

Comment: Have you ever read an error messages `template or render function not defined.`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) you'll see that the HTML should be wrapped in the `<template>` element. So change your component to:

```
<template>
  <h1> test connection </h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SelectComponent',
    data () {
     return {}
    }
  }
</script>
```